# MVCController class versus ApiController class

Tags: webapi

What are the advantages and disadvantages if I make my web api controller inherit from MvcController class instead of ApiController class?

Answer (score 0):

If your Controller inherits from `MvcController` class it won't be an API Service , It'll become an `MvcController` that need `view` and will be displayed in Html Page .